# Evaluation function for minimax

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, cs50, minimax

Hello everyone I am currently taking CS50AI course. 1st assignment is creating a tictactoe AI with minimax function. My problem is this: As far as I understand, there has to be a static evaluation for positions of the game. I was trying to write something like this in pseudocode :

```
If next move is a winning move:
    return 10 point
elif opponent is going to win stop him:
    return 8 point
```

kind of thing. But when I checked others minvalue - max value function there was no such a thing.

```
def minimax(board):
    """
    Returns the optimal action for the current player on the board.
    """
    currentactions = actions(board)
    if player(board) == X:
        vT = -math.inf
        move = set()
        for action in currentactions:
            v, count = maxvalue(result(board,action), 0)
            if v > vT:
                vT = v
                move = action
    else:
        vT = math.inf
        move = set()
        for action in currentactions:
            v, count = minvalue(result(board,action), 0)
            if v < vT:
                vT = v
                move = action
    print(count)
    return move

    def maxvalue(board, count):
        """
        Calculates the max value of a given board recursively together with minvalue
        """
    
        if terminal(board): return utility(board), count+1
    
        v = -math.inf
        posactions = actions(board)
    
        for action in posactions:
            vret, count = minvalue(result(board, action), count)
            v = max(v, vret)
        
        return v, count+1
    
    def minvalue(board, count):
        """
        Calculates the min value of a given board recursively together with maxvalue
        """
    
        if terminal(board): return utility(board), count+1
    
        v = math.inf
        posactions = actions(board)
    
        for action in posactions:
            vret, count = maxvalue(result(board, action), count)
            v = min(v, vret)
        
        return v, count+1
```

This is sikburn's tictactoe implementation's max - min functions. I could not understand what outcome will come from the max or min value functions. Can anyone clarify my logic please ? By the way, `terminal()` function checks if the game ended (has a winner or tie) and `result()` function takes a board and action as an input and returns the resultant board. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

In the `utility` function (not included in your code), you probably assigned 1 to X victory, -1 to O victory, and 0 otherwise. The `minimax` function calls `minvalue` and `maxvalue` recursively, for all possible moves, until it comes to the end of the game, be it a tie or a victory. Then it call `utility` to get the value. Both `minvalue` and `maxvalue` assure X and O will always select the best possible moves.

Don't forget to check if the board is terminal and return `None` if it is, before proceding, in the `minimax` function.

Swap the the calling of `minvalue` and `maxvalue` functions in `minimax`: for X, call `minvalue` (because X wants to know O next move) and for O, call `maxvalue` (for the same reason).

If you want to see the evalution at each iteration, you can print something like `f"Minvalue: {v}, Iteration: {count+1}"` and `f"Maxvalue: {v}, Iteration: {count+1}"` at the end of `minvalue` and `maxvalue` functions, just before returning those values. I think it would be easier to understand.

I hppe I clarified your doubts.